# Actions to take against paid collection

Tags: united-states, collections

I received a note from a lender about a debit I had with GAP. It was completely unintentional and I didn't even know about it until then. The firm is in MS and I was living in CA at the time, while GAP store was in NY. I decided to pay because I was moving to Europe and did not want to have issues, but I noticed that the record is still on my credit score. Is it still possible to do anything to have it removed?

Comment: I have had one successfully removed for a Doctor's copayment that I missed (had surgery, so there were tons of them).  I contacted the company and they were able to remove it.  Often times the most difficult part will be finding out who owned the debt and how to contact them.  Good luck.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to inquire about it using the online forms provided by the credit score agencies? I noticed that you can dispute and select "Debit Paid" as a reason. Would there be any drawback?

Comment: I'll try to look into that this evening and tomorrow.  Mine occurred about 8 years ago, so I directly contacted the agency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single, small item isn't going to destroy your credit, especially if you pay.  However, before you pay it, get it *in writing* that your payment fully satisfies the debt and they will mark it as such on the report.

You can also ask to have it removed, but even if they don't your credit score will recover quickly.

Don't do it again however, because multiple items will cause you bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally too late once it's on there.

However - you can always ask to have it removed. If handled diplomatically on your part, you just might come across one of those credit agencies that are happy to help you out. Ask.